# Nim: lambdas with void return type cause compiler crash

Tags: lambda, closures, nim-lang

See this minimal example:

```
import sugar

type TestLambda = () -> void
type NamedTestLambda = tuple[name: string, lambda: TestLambda]

var testNil: TestLambda = () => void


var funcs: seq[NamedTestLambda] = @[
    (name: "nil", lambda: testNil),
]
```

This causes the following error output:

```
Error: internal error: getTypeDescAux(tyVoid)
No stack traceback available
To create a stacktrace, rerun compilation with './koch temp c <file>', see https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/intern.html#debugging-the-compiler for details
     Error: Build failed for package: nim_snake
        ... Execution failed with exit code 256
```

While the code seems to compile without problem when we change the return type to int:

```
import sugar

type TestLambda = () -> int
type NamedTestLambda = tuple[name: string, lambda: TestLambda]

var testNil: TestLambda = () => 1


var funcs: seq[NamedTestLambda] = @[
    (name: "nil", lambda: testNil),
]
```

Should I report this to the nim language forum, or is there something I did wrong here?

Nim 1.6.16, compiling to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue lies in the `testNil` variable which returns `void` instead of just discarding with `discard` or not returning a value.
As per [this discussion on nim forum](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/542) void is only useful to say that something has no type and if used as a return value in a proc/func, just means the function doesn't return a value. Using it in `var testnil: TestLambda = () => void` is wrong and should have been `var testnil: TestLambda = () => (discard)` or even `var testnil: TestLambda = () => echo "void"`.

Comment: `var testnil: TestLambda = () => discard ` does not compile. 
"Error: expression expected, but found 'keyword discard'"

Comment: Sorry the issue is from the sugar module's proc template( `() =>`) evaluation process. If you wrapped the `discard` in a new block with`()` it will work. See https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=4LQS

Comment: Yes, the () block is essential, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `=>` macro may be doing something wrong trying to detect which is the return type of that empty lambda.

In this case, you can use the vanilla way to create lambdas:

```
var testNil: TestLambda = proc() = discard
```

Answer (score 1):

oof. sorry:

- you tried 'discard' it didn't work.
- you tried 'void' it crashed the compiler.

as @Claypant says: this works to create a void lambda returning void:

```
var testNil: TestLambda = () => (discard)
```

this is not your fault, it's clearly nothing anyone else thought to test.
i've reported it on github [here](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/23048)

the dirty reason why `(discard)` works, but `discard` doesnt is because the former is an expression, while the latter is a statement.